# Break lines in tcblisting

Tags: tcolorbox, tcblisting, tcbset, breaklines

**Here is my MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{sidebyside,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}}}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
  comment and listing,
  comment style={scale=2},
  pdf comment,
  freeze pdf,
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex,
}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\(1 = =2 = 2= 22=123=3= 13=1 313= 1 31=3131=3\)
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

**It produces:**

[image]

***The question:*** how to achieve this result with small red arrow breaking long line?

[image]
Thank you in advanve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- `breaklines` and `postbreak` are options from the listings package, not from the tcolorbox package. You can't directly use them in `\tcbset{...}`
- there is a syntax error in `\textcolor{red{..}}`

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  sidebyside,
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}
  }
}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
  comment and listing,
  comment style={scale=2},
  pdf comment,
  freeze pdf,
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex,
}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\(1 = =2 = 2= 22=123=3= 13=1 313= 1 31=3131=3\)
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to remove thin black frame around standalone result?

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh If you have a new question, please ask a new question